# Using begin inside Ruby method to catch errors

Tags: ruby

I saw this somewhere but don't really know why you need a `begin` here:

```
  def some_method
    @ivar ||= begin
      if ...
        ...
      end
    end
  end
```

Does it help catch an error or some sort? What is its purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be used to provide multiple instructions to set the `@ivar`. Or to say it differently, to provide a block of code to set that value.

Answer (score 1):

This idiom is called memoization.

```
@foo ||= some_expression
```

Sets `@foo` to value of `some_expression` if it's not already set.

Now, in ruby most everything is an expression. Including `begin .. end` block. So yes, begin/end there is just to group a few lines of code into one expression.

Comment: Though, while it works, it's probably another of those things that should be written a bit more verbosely. `||= begin` is awkward.

Comment: @theTinMan: yeah, I normally do `@foo ||= compute_foo`. But maybe sometimes you _can't_ have a separate method.

Comment: I understand what `||=` but what does the `begin` do?